# For what values $\alpha>0$ does $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^{-\alpha}}{1+\alpha^{-k}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As in the title, I want to find all $\alpha>0$ such that $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^{-\alpha}}{1+\alpha^{-k}}$ converges. A small hint will do.

Comment: Distinguish the cases $\alpha<1$, $\alpha>1$, and $\alpha=1$. In the first two cases, try to find a convergent dominating series (i.e., use the comparison test for series).

Answer (score 0):

Small hints:

For $\alpha>1$, $1+\alpha^{-k}>1$, which means $k^{-\alpha}/(1+\alpha^{-k})<k^{-\alpha}$.

For $\alpha=1$, what is arguably the most well-known divergent series?

For $0<\alpha<1$, compare the term to $\alpha^{-k}$.